# Trigger a dash dashboard on a button click

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am working on a dash app, where I try to integrate [ExplainerDashboard](https://explainerdashboard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

If I do it like this:

```
app.config.external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP]

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Submit', id='submit', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='container-button-basic', children='')
])

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = titanic_survive()
model = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
explainer = ClassifierExplainer(model, X_test, y_test)
db = ExplainerDashboard(explainer, shap_interaction=False)
db.explainer_layout.register_callbacks(app)     

@app.callback(
    Output('container-button-basic', 'children'),
    Input('submit', 'n_clicks'),
)
def update_output(n_clicks):

    if n_clicks == 1:
        return db.explainer_layout.layout()
```

The dashboard gets triggered on the button click, however, it is calculated before I click the button and when the dash starts. If I change it and put the calculations inside the callback like this, I get the dashboard but it looks the register callback doesn't work and all the plots are empty

```
app.config.external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP]

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Submit', id='submit', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='container-button-basic', children='')
])

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = titanic_survive()
model = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
explainer = ClassifierExplainer(model, X_test, y_test)

@app.callback(
    Output('container-button-basic', 'children'),
    Input('submit', 'n_clicks'),
)
def update_output(n_clicks):

    if n_clicks == 1:
        db = ExplainerDashboard(explainer, shap_interaction=False) 
        db.explainer_layout.register_callbacks(app)     
        return db.explainer_layout.layout()
```

Comment: You could initialize the dashboard layout in a hidden div `html.Div(hiddent=True, ...)` and set hidden to false + populate components on the dashboard inside the callback.

Comment: My problem is that calculations for the dashboard takes too much time and there is a non-configurable timeout for the initial load only to 60secs. That's why I try to trigger it on a button click

Comment: @Tasos Are you sure that the timeout for the callback itself is long enough? Typically, the timeout for a callback is around 30s (e.g. on Heroku), which would be too short for your use case. Generally, for calculations that take this long (> 1 minute), I would recommend an async approach.

Comment: I am using Dataiku to host the Dash app. it is a Data Science platform and the timeout to initiate the Dash app is be default 60 seconds. There is no way to configure that, so what I try to do is to find a way to open the Dash app as quick as possible and then handle the computations inside the ExplainerDashboard where there is no timeout. Do you have any idea how to do it async?

Comment: @Tasos Check my answer please. I tested it on my system. Any questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason **why** your example doesn't work is that in Dash, callbacks must be registered *before* the server starts. Hence, you cannot register new callbacks from within a callback.

##### Data pre-processing pipeline

I think the cleanest solution would be move the data processing to a pre-processing pipeline. It could be something as simple as a notebook running on the Dataiku node. The code would be along the lines of

```
from explainerdashboard import ClassifierExplainer
from explainerdashboard.datasets import titanic_survive
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = titanic_survive()
model = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
explainer = ClassifierExplainer(model, X_test, y_test)
explainer.dump("/data/dataiku/titanic.joblib") # save to some writeable location
```

The corresponding webapp code would be something like,

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Dash
from explainerdashboard import ClassifierExplainer, ExplainerDashboard

explainer = ClassifierExplainer.from_file("/data/dataiku/titanic.joblib")  # load pre-processed data
db = ExplainerDashboard(explainer, shap_interaction=False)
app.config.external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP]
app.layout = db.explainer_layout.layout()
db.explainer_layout.register_callbacks(app)
```

The deployment process would then be to (1) run the notebook and (2) (re)start the webapp backend. Note that this process must be repeated for the app to pickup new data.

##### Callback registration using mock data

Another approach could be to use a mock dataset that is small, but has the same structure as your normal (large) dataset, for constructing the `ExplainerDashboard` during app initialisation. This approach enables fast initial loading, and callback registration before app start. You could then use a callback to load the complete dataset afterwards, i.e. similar to your original idea. Here is some example code,

```
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html, Dash, Output, Input, dcc
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
from explainerdashboard import ClassifierExplainer, ExplainerDashboard
from explainerdashboard.datasets import titanic_survive
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


def get_explainer(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, limit=-1):
    model = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train[:limit], y_train[:limit])
    return ClassifierExplainer(model, X_test[:limit], y_test[:limit])


def inject_inplace(src, dst):
    for attr in dir(dst):
        try:
            setattr(dst, attr, getattr(src, attr))
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        except NotImplementedError:
            pass


X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = titanic_survive()
# Create explainer with minimal data to ensure fast initial load.
explainer = get_explainer(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, limit=5)
dashboard = ExplainerDashboard(explainer, shap_interaction=False)
# Setup app with (hidden) dummy classifier layout.
dummy_layout = html.Div(dashboard.explainer_layout.layout(), style=dict(display="none"))
app = Dash()  # not needed in Dataiku
app.config.external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP]
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Submit', id='submit', n_clicks=0),
    dcc.Loading(html.Div(id='container', children=dummy_layout), fullscreen=True)
])
# Register the callback before the app starts.
dashboard.explainer_layout.register_callbacks(app)


@app.callback(Output('container', 'children'), Input('submit', 'n_clicks'))
def load_complete_dataset(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks != 1:
        raise PreventUpdate

    # Replace in-memory references to the full dataset to sure callbacks target the full dataset.
    full_explainer = get_explainer(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
    inject_inplace(full_explainer, explainer)

    return ExplainerDashboard(explainer, shap_interaction=False).explainer_layout.layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(port=9024, debug=False)
```

Comment: Thanks @emher. This is a good idea I thought as well. However, I am not sure it is applicable. The idea is to use it as a plugin where the user will open the dashboard. This approach requires to manually initiate the notebook, save it somewhere as you said and then run the dashboard.

Comment: What about creating a scenario that runs the notebook (or the maybe just the Python code directly), and then restarts the webapp? You could then schedule the scenario to run e.g. one per day (outside business hours) to keep the data up to date

Comment: @Tasos I have updated the answer adding a different approach using a (small) mock dataset for the callback registrating during app initialisation.

Comment: Hi @ember. The mock db approach looks really interesting. However, I am not sure it works. When I try it, the dashboard still has the sampled dataset. I can see it for example in the Classification Stats tab in the Confusion matrix where the sum of the values are 10.

Comment: Edit: I do the sample in the test dataset since the dashboard uses that instead the training dataset. So, training won't impact the loading time a lot

Comment: @Tasos I have updated the example code for the 2nd approach correcting a bug, cleaning the code a bit, and adding sub sampling of the test data also (as your test data is large, this is probably necessary).

Comment: It's working now. Thank you a lot! It's really impressive

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

My understanding per my experiments with Dash (a React app) is callbacks do get registered after Dash app's initialisation (as you are doing inside a callback in your second code) but they don't get passed to the web page as the React app on the web page is already loaded, so if you refresh page, the React app gets all callbacks (even the new ones registered after Dash app's initialisation).

**Long version**

The problem with your second code wherein you are instantiating `ExplainerDashboard` in the callback is that the callbacks registered now by ExplainerDashboard is not passed on to the already-loaded web page.

The reason being Dash loads the callbacks on page load, so any callbacks added after the page is loaded do not work. I did various experiments after checking the code of `ExplainerDashboard` and reading Dash's documentation. And fortunately, I came across a classic trick (from web dev.) that overrides the issue.

The trick is to initiate `ExplainerDashboard` on the first page load, show a in-progress message, then activate the button after it's initiated, then load the initiated `ExplainerDashboard` on button click. Below is the tested and verified code for the same. Of course, it's a POC, which can be improved to put into production.

```py
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from explainerdashboard import ClassifierExplainer, ExplainerDashboard
from explainerdashboard.datasets import titanic_survive


app = Dash(__name__)

app.index_string = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {%metas%}
        <title>{%title%}</title>
        {%favicon%}
        {%css%}
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if (document.getElementById("explainer_is_loaded")) {
                        console.log("Y");
                        document.getElementById("submit").textContent = "Submit";
                    } else {
                        console.log("N");
                        window.location = "/";  /* refresh the page */
                    }
                }, 5000);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        {%app_entry%}
        <footer>
            {%config%}
            {%scripts%}
            {%renderer%}
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
'''

# app.config.external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP]

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Loading... Please wait...', id='submit', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='container-button-basic', children=''),

    html.Button('', id='hidden-btn1', n_clicks=0, hidden=True),
    html.Div(id='hidden-div1', children='', hidden=True),
])

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = titanic_survive()
model = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
explainer = ClassifierExplainer(model, X_test, y_test)

db = None


@app.callback(
    Output('hidden-div1', 'children'),
    Input('hidden-btn1', 'n_clicks'),
)
def init_explainer(n_clicks):
    global db

    if not db:
        db = ExplainerDashboard(explainer, shap_interaction=False)
        db.explainer_layout.register_callbacks(app)
    else:
        return html.Div(id='explainer_is_loaded', hidden=True),


@app.callback(
    Output('container-button-basic', 'children'),
    Input('submit', 'n_clicks'),
)
def load_explainer(n_clicks):
    global db

    if n_clicks >= 1 and db:
        return db.explainer_layout.layout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Let me explain new parts of the program in detail:

1. `app.index_string`

This part customizes Dash's HTML Index Template to include our page refresh code. It refreshes the page every 5 seconds until it finds `#explainer_is_loaded` element.

2. `init_explainer(n_clicks)`

This part adds a callback that runs on page load as I am not checking for `n_checks` in this callback. So, we initiates the ExplainerDashboard under this callback.

3. `load_explainer(n_clicks)`

This part is your own callback modified to simply return `db.explainer_layout.layout()` when the button is clicked on the web page.

4. `global db`

Since the ExplainerDashboard is instantiated and used in different functions (and on different page loads), we needed a global variable to store its object.

**References**

- https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources
- https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks
- https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks

Comment: I just tried running the code, but I get a lot of "ID not found in layout" errors in the console. Are you able to run the code without errors? Also, could you elaborate on how your code should make it possible to register callbacks after app initialisation? On a different note, the use of global variables in Dash is discouraged, see e.g. the section "Why Global Variables Will Break Your App" in [the docs](https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks)

Comment: Hi @emher, "ID not found in layout" errors are side-effects, but they are only visible as we are running Dash in dev or debug mode. My understanding per my experiments with Dash (a React app) is  callbacks do get registered after Dash app's initialisation but they don't get passed to the web page as the React app on the web page is already loaded, so if you refresh page, the React app gets all callbacks (even the new ones registered after Dash app's initialisation). As for global variables, they are usually discouraged but they can be necessary evil, sometimes! Thanks.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the detailed answer. However, I need to reject it since the Dash mentions that it will break if you use global variables. So, it's not a bad practice only but something that will make the app not running properly. I appreciate your effort tho